# PL/SQL array manipulation function

Tags: oracle, user-defined-types

I'm new in PL/SQL. I have a matrix stored in the `DB` as a nested table. Something like, 
the matrix is stored as a TABLE of objects (and objects are t1 number, t2 number, ... t100 number)

To to get the matrix it would be `select x.* from test t, table(t.matrix) x where...` , returning

```
|T1|T2|T3|...|T100|
```

I want to create a function that returns the sum over the row to be called using SQL only, something equivalent to

```
select sum(x.T1),sum(x.T2)...sum(x.T100) from test t, table(t.matrix) x where ...
```

Something like `select bigsum(x.*) from table t, table(t.matrix)`

It will be called several times, and I don't want to write the 100 columns every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum the values from 100 different columns, you're going to have to explicitly list those 100 columns at some point.  You can encapsulate that logic for that expression in a view or a function or a pipelined table function or some other construct so that you don't have to repeat the expression many times, you just have to reference the abstraction you've created (i.e. call the function that sums the 100 values).

Although it would likely complicate the problem rather than simplifying it, you could potentially create a solution that uses dynamic SQL to generate the 100 columns names and the expression to add them together if you really, really want to avoid writing out 100 column names.  It is highly unlikely, however, that the extra complexity of resorting to dynamic SQL would be beneficial unless there are substantial requirements that you haven't mentioned here that make writing out the column names more than a bit repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

> " it'll be called several times, and don't want to write the 100
>   columns every time"

Why not create a view?  Write it once, call it as many times as you like:

```
create or replace view bigsum
     select t.whatever
            , sum(x.T1) as sum_t1
            , sum(x.T2) as sum_t2
            ...
            , sum(x.T100) as sum_t100
      from test t
           , table(t.matrix) x
      group by t.whatever
```

You would need to include identifying columns from TEST to allow you to join the view to other tables.  This approach would give you something close to want you want:

```
select *
from bigsum
where whatever = 23
```

You can reduce the amount of typing further by processing a result set from the data dictionary view  [USER_TYPE_ATTRS](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/refrn20295.htm#REFRN20295) (or a SQL*Plus description) in a decent text editor with a regex search'n'replace.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work as the identifier is unique for each row, so the view doesn't compile unless I know in advance which rows. Is there any other way using a function?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean: all identifiers are unique.  Please post your a complete description of your data structures.  If you don't provide *all the relevant information* you can't expect us to give you a workable solution.

Comment: I really appreciate your help (and for editing my post), besides the T.? columns I have an ID column. What I need to do several times, is to query the total sum of the selected rows given a join with another table using id, for example : select bigsum(x.*) from table t, table(t.matrix) where t.ID in (0,19,30,55)   If I create a view, the ID is not a single group function, that's why I think writing a procedure or function might be the way to go, but I can't find any help anywhere

Comment: Okay, now I understand what you're trying to do.  Alas right now I don't have the time to rustle up a solution.

Answer (score -1):

you can create a function in the below given form depending on your condition and if you require parameter then you can add them while creating function and use them in the condition required

```
create or replace function bigsum
return number
as
sumall number;
begin
  select (sum(x.T1),sum(x.T2)...sum(x.T100)) into sumall 
   from test t, table(t.matrix) x where .(your condition).. ;
 return sumall;
end;/

and call it in the manner

select  bigsum from dual;
```

Comment: whats the reason for downvote ... already i mentioned if its parameter based then one can declare parameter and use them at required condition in where clause